# GUI for powercfg battery report

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a GUI for the powercfg battery report. I've written the below, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
    saveDialog.Title = "Save your battery report";
    saveDialog.Filter = "HTML | *.html";
    var defaultSavePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    saveDialog.InitialDirectory = defaultSavePath;
    saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    var saveLocation = saveDialog.FileName;

    if (saveLocation != null)
    {
        saveLocation = "\"" + saveLocation + "\"";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "powercfg.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = " /batteryreport /output " + saveLocation;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"it doesn't seem to work"* mean? If it doesn't work you need to describe exactly what is happening, what errors you are getting, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. When it executes Process.Start, no file is saved to the desired location. 

 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start returned.BasePriority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' int {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: When I output the errors I receive   
"The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded.\r\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my OS is 64 bit, in project properties I un-checked *Prefer 32-bit* checkbox in *Build* tab and it worked properly.

1. Right click on Project → *Properties*
2. *Build* Tab → *General*
3. Set *Platform Target* combo box : *Any CPU*, *Prefer 32-bit* check box : unchecked

It also works when you choose the same bitness as your OS for Platform Target. For example X4.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help